MQTT Connection Error to AWS IOT Core With ESP32-S3
I made test code with mqtt communicate with AWS IOT in ESP-IDF.
I made sample handler and save root ca in global ca store.
and then I set the Mqtt Config.
I tried to Connect MQTT With AWS IOT Core With below Code
const char *mqtt_broker_url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.iot.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com";
const char *mqtt_client_id = "ESP-TEST";
const uint16_t mqtt_port = 8883;

extern const uint8_t root_ca_pem_start[] asm("_binary_root_ca_pem_start");
extern const uint8_t root_ca_pem_end[] asm("_binary_root_ca_pem_end");
extern const uint8_t device_cert_crt_start[] asm("_binary_certificate_pem_crt_start");
extern const uint8_t device_cert_crt_end[] asm("_binary_certificate_pem_crt_end");
extern const uint8_t device_private_key_start[] asm("_binary_private_pem_key_start");
extern const uint8_t device_private_key_end[] asm("_binary_private_pem_key_end");

void mqtt_event_handler(void *handler_args, esp_event_base_t base, int32_t event_id, void *event_data)
{
    ESP_LOGD(TAG, "Event dispatched from event loop base=%s, event_id=%ld", base, event_id);
}

void app_main(void)
{
    ...WIFI CONNECT...
    //Wait for WiFi to connect
    vTaskDelay(5000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_tls_init_global_ca_store());
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_tls_set_global_ca_store(
        (const unsigned char *)root_ca_pem_start,
        root_ca_pem_end - root_ca_pem_start
    ));
    vTaskDelay(5000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);

    esp_mqtt_client_config_t mqtt_cfg = {
        .broker.address.hostname = mqtt_broker_url,
        .broker.address.port = mqtt_port,
        .broker.address.transport = MQTT_TRANSPORT_OVER_SSL,
        .broker.verification.use_global_ca_store = true,
        .credentials.authentication.certificate = (const char *)device_cert_crt_start,
        .credentials.authentication.certificate_len = device_cert_crt_end - device_cert_crt_start,
        .credentials.authentication.key = (const char *)device_private_key_start, 
        .credentials.authentication.key_len = device_private_key_end - device_private_key_start,
        .task.priority = MAX_PRIROTY - 2,
        .task.stack_size = 1024 * 8,
    };

    esp_mqtt_client_handle_t client = esp_mqtt_client_init(&mqtt_cfg);
    esp_mqtt_client_register_event(client, ESP_EVENT_ANY_ID, mqtt_event_handler, NULL);
    esp_mqtt_client_start(client);
}

But Connection Error Occured.
E (489371) esp-tls-mbedtls: read error :-0x004C:
E (489371) transport_base: esp_tls_conn_read error, errno=Socket is not connected
E (489381) mqtt_client: esp_mqtt_handle_transport_read_error: transport_read() error: errno=128
E (489391) mqtt_client: esp_mqtt_connect: mqtt_message_receive() returned -1
E (489391) mqtt_client: MQTT connect failed

What part of my code is wrong?

I Forgot to set the client Id... haha...
I added ".credentials.client_id = mqtt_client_id" then it works!

You may consider to delete your post instead of keeping it.
